# Search database with lat and long by radius using php mysql

Tags: php, sql, json, jquery

Im trying to develop a small site which retrieves a results from a database by a set radius and places them on a map. 
I use Google maps api to get the lat and long from there search criteria, pass these to my php script which queries the database and returns the result set as a JSON object.

Im having small a problem sending both the lat and long to the php using json.

My main problem is that my sql to search the database appears to be wrong as it just retrieves the first 10 results in my database. I want it to return the first 10 results within the radius from the search point.

Here is my ajax code

```
function showCarPark(location)
{
    var lat = location.lat();
    var lng = location.lng();
    //alert("Lat: " +lat.toFixed(6));
    //alert("Lng: " +lng.toFixed(6));
    document.getElementById('carParkResults').innerHTML = "";
    var criterion = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var count = 0;
    $.ajax({    
              url: 'process.php',
              type: 'GET',
              data: "lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) 
              {
                  jQuery.each(data, function()
                  {
                    $('<p>').text("Car Park: " + data[count].name).appendTo('#carParkResults');
                    placeCarParks(data[count].postcode,data[count].name, data[count].street, data[count].type);
                    count++;
                  });
              },
              error: function(e) 
              {
                //called when there is an error
                console.log(e.message);
                alert("error" + e.message);
              }
    });
```

And here is my php script

```
$rad = 20;
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lng = 1.4681464; //put a temporary number in as it wont pass the lng in the JSON

$sql="SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(long) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM carpark HAVING distance < 15 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $rows[] = $r;

echo json_encode($rows);
```

The columns in my table are called lat and long
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your case try to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('".$lat."')) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos( radians(long) - radians('".$lng."')) + sin(radians('".$lat."')) * 
sin(radians(lat)))) 
AS distance 
FROM carpark WHERE distance < 15 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: It's doesn't work with WHERE, because you use your counted variable. So you need to use HAVING, than it's working. 

Have fun ;)

Comment: For those wondering what `3959` stands for, it's the earth radius in miles. `6378` is in kilometers.

Answer (score 9):

I had no trouble using HAVING. iLLin's answer is misleading. Here is an example of a correct query to find the distance from New York City:

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(radians('40.7142')) * cos(radians(latitudeColName)) * cos( radians(longitudeColName) - radians('-74.0064')) + sin(radians('40.7142')) * sin(radians(latitudeColName)))) AS distance FROM myTable HAVING distance < 15 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Change the line in the jQuery request to use this notation {name : value, name : value}:

```
          data: {lat : lat, long : long},
```

Answer (score 1):

Larry Ullman did something very similar in his book "PHP 5 Advanced: Visual Quickpro Guide."

Looking at his example code, try this to calculate distance:

```
ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($lat)) 
* SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) 
+ COS(RADIANS($lat))  
* COS(RADIANS(latitude))
* COS(RADIANS($long - longitude)))) * 69.09) AS distance
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$lat.") ) * cos( radians( ".$lat." ) ) * cos( radians( ".$long." ) - radians(".$long.") ) + sin( radians(".$lat.") ) * sin( radians( ".$lat." ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM carpark HAVING distance < 15 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 10"
```

You need to fix your query to pull in the latitude and longitude values.  You are just passing in the word lat/long in a few spots.  Compare this query to yours to see what I mean.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Only if the variables are not quoted.  Who says they weren't further up?  Regardless, this isn't what the question was about.

Comment: It’s still good to point out. It would be naïve to say that there aren’t people who find answers on Stack Overflow after a Google search and then copy-and-paste answers.

Comment: I'm not arguing with you about that, but maybe you should highlight the original authors question as that is clearly SQL injection.  Why you picked this comment i have no idea and it's not even the accepted answer.  So if your intent was to highlight that, I think you picked the wrong answer :P